# Not able to access the jobData from Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, scala, quartz-scheduler

I am new to quartz schdeuler, and I am trying explore the functionality of quartzto access the jobdata using a simple program, but getting `null`

my program

```
    object MyMain extends App{
  lazy val quartz = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler
  val Job = new Job {
    override def execute(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) = {
      println("Event")
      val jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail.getJobDataMap
      println(jobDataMap.getString("aa"))
    }
  }

  val job = JobBuilder.newJob(Job.getClass)
    .withIdentity("Job", "Group")
    .build

  val trigger: Trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger
    .withIdentity("Trigger", "Group")
    .usingJobData("aa","bb")
    .withSchedule(
      CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
    .build

  quartz.start
  quartz.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
}
```

instead of returning the value of key `aa` i.e `bb` I am getting `null` 
Can anyone point out what should be correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution, it worked when I used `getMergedJobDataMap` instead of `getJobDataMap`

```
val jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail.getMergedJobDataMap
```